# How to add a sequential number to a row in an Insert Statement for a Master Table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table A has historical records.
Table B has 100 new records.

I need to append the data from Table B to Table A. Table A was built with a Row Number(using the Row_Number function) The last record entry had a row number of 100, how do I append my new data into that table and continue the row record to 101 and so on?

Comment: You use the exact same technique - just add 100 to the value generated by row_number.  And perhaps now is a good time to give the people that have provided useful information to you some credit - mark the appropriate answers to your questions.

Comment: Why not just use an `IDENTITY` on the table, if you want an always ascending value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @MaxValue INT;

SELECT @MaxValue = MAX([record_id])
FROM TableA;

INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -- or order by something else you need
       +
       @MaxValue
       ,* 
FROM TableB 

COMMIT TRAN
```